# CSS or JQUERY Vertical Scrollbar BUT WITHOUT SETTING HEIGHT

Tags: jquery, html, css, scrollbar

I have some Jquery/CSS web pages which dynamically take into account screen width and then positions the DIV cells either as 1 column or 2 column.  Adding a new cell is as simple as creating a new DIV and the page formats itself accordingly.

My main issue is that I cannot show a vertical scrollbar.  While I know that I can use my mouse wheel to scroll down, the site owner wants a vertical scrollbar so that others may know as well.  There are tons of examples of Jquery vertical scrollbars out there, but they **all** require setting a height or a maxheight, which I cannot set because the page handles its own formatting.

An example of one of the pages is here:
[Example](http://www.writtenbyjoelle.com/main-press.htm)

Is there any way I can get a vertical scrollbar onto this page that would produce the same results as it currntly does simply using the mouse wheel

Thanks!

Comment: why not use css overflow:auto?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first problem is you have margins, and a width of 100%. The margins are added to the width of the block. Because of that your .parent isn't totally visible on your page.

```
div.parent {
    width:auto;
    overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

Comment: I changed a bit of my answer, the way I tested it on your website works for me. If you're using mac with magic mouse or touchpad the scrollbar will be invisble unless you're scrolling;

Comment: THANK YOU!  I had been trying for a week before I posted here.

Answer (score 1):

In your `.parent` div you have a `margin-left: 2%` and `margin-right: 2%`.  Remove the `margin-right: 2%` and make the width 98% and your scrollbar will appear.

The reason for this is that your margins push the scrollbar off of the screen, when the width is 100%.

I would also suggest removing the `overflow-y: scroll` from the `<html>` tag, as it just seems to create a giant disabled scrollbar, could be confusing to users and seems to be a waste of space.

Comment: @danrhul Wrong, only the former is required, the latter is only a suggestion.

Comment: Lol he is correct, removing the margin-right and adding width: auto on the #parent div fixes the issue! O.o

Answer (score 1):

The margins on the `div.parent` element are shifting it too far to the left hiding the scrollbar. You should change these to padding or remove the 100% width on it:

```
div.parent {
    /* width: 100%; */
    margin-left: 2%;
    padding-right: 2%;
}
```